# canvas.drawText() draws text at wrong coordinates

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm currently developing a little android game. It is about shooting down enemy aircraft. I'm drawing the content of the actual game with the build in [Android Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html). To tell the user his score and other information, I use

```
canvas.drawText(...);
```

My problem is that, after a short time, the text is drawed at a wrong x-coordinate. I checked the affected variables and they have the correct values stored.
This is the sourcecode:

```
c.drawText(this.you + ": " + this.activity.getLocalScore(), GameActivitySinglePlayer.SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.02f, GameActivitySinglePlayer.SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.07f, this.smallText);//works
c.drawText(this.enemy + ": " + this.activity.getAndroidScore(), GameActivitySinglePlayer.SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.8f, GameActivitySinglePlayer.SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.07f, this.smallText);//works
c.drawText(this.oldFps + " FPS", GameActivitySinglePlayer.SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.45f, GameActivitySinglePlayer.SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.05f, this.smallText);//works sometime
c.drawText(this.activity.lives + " " + this.lives, GameActivitySinglePlayer.SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.45f, GameActivitySinglePlayer.SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.091f, this.smallText);//works sometime
c.drawText("Level " + this.activity.level, GameActivitySinglePlayer.SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.45f, GameActivitySinglePlayer.SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.132f, this.smallText);//works sometime

System.out.println("width: " + GameActivitySinglePlayer.SCREEN_WIDTH + " height " + GameActivitySinglePlayer.SCREEN_HEIGHT); //Prints correct values (1280 and 720)
```

[Here is a combined image of the fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI395.png)

Please note that I added the red rectangles afterwards to improve visibility of the error.

Thank you for any help and improvement proposals.